# cpprestsdk Websocket TLS Handshake failed error

Tags: websocket, cpprest-sdk

I'm new to cpprestsdk and I need a websocket client. So far I'm able to get the  a websocket-client to connect over wss server with validate_certificates set to false. When I enable it I'm getting "TLS Handshake failed" error. On checking the logs from the server, I see the client is sending in the initial handshake message and when the server responds it send a failure message.

When I set the certificate validation to false the client sends a success message.

How do I configure the websocket client to validate self signed certificate along with CA issued certificates?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like on Windows machine the SSL context is not able to load the certificates from root CA store. Fixed it by loading the certificate and assigning the same to ssl context.

```
 websocket_client_config config;
    config.set_ssl_context_callback([this] 
   (boost::asio::ssl::context& ctx) {
    // attach X509_STORE to boost ssl context
    HCERTSTORE hStore = CertOpenSystemStore(0, "ROOT");
   if (hStore == NULL) {
   return;
   }
   m_RootCACertificateStore = X509_STORE_new();
   PCCERT_CONTEXT pContext = NULL;
   while ((pContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(hStore, 
   pContext)) != NULL) {
   // convert from DER to internal format
   X509* x509 = d2i_X509(NULL,
   (const unsigned char**)&pContext->pbCertEncoded,
    pContext->cbCertEncoded);
    if (x509 != NULL) {
      X509_STORE_add_cert(m_RootCACertificateStore, x509);
      X509_free(x509);
     }
   }

   CertFreeCertificateContext(pContext);
   CertCloseStore(hStore, 0);     
 
   SSL_CTX_set1_cert_store(
   ctx.native_handle(),m_RootCACertificateStore );
        });`
```